# Link to snapshot from TV-IP110WN

Tags: webcam, snapshot

I have a Trendnet TV-IP110WN camera on my local network. I'd like to embed a link to a current snapshot from this camera on a web page.

I can't seem to find any information on how to get a snapshot from the camera. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dug through the GPL source for the camera, and finally found it.

http://ipaddress:port/cgi/jpg/image.cgi will get it for you.